# Angular AuthGuard - NgRx - Universal on reload redirection

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular-universal, auth-guard

**The problem is with Angular Universal, if I build app without Universal It's working fine but with Angular Universal this is the problem.**

I'm using angular with ngrx and Angular Universal, on every reload I'm sending request to the backend then retreiveing user data. If route is protected with auth guard on reload if user is logged in first it redirects to /login then after 0.5 seconds redirects to protected route, data is loaded everything works fine, but why It's showing /login first ?

AuthGuard

```
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      return this.store.select(fromAuth.selectAuthState).pipe(
        map(authState => authState.isInitializing),
        filter((isInit) => !isInit),
        tap((data) => console.log(data)),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.store.select(fromAuth.selectAuthState).pipe(
            map(authState => authState),
            map((isAuth) => {
              console.log(isAuth);
              if (isAuth.user) return true;
              return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
            }),
            take(1)
            );
        })
      );
```

Initial state in Ngrx/store

```
export const initialState: State = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isInitializing: true
```

On login success and on login fail **isInitializing**  is set to false

```
  on(AuthActions.logInSuccess, (state) => {
    return {
      isInitializing: false,
      isAuthenticated: true,
    };
  }),
```

I'm dispatching isLoggedIn action in APP_INITIALIZER

```
export function appInitializerFactory(
  store: Store<any>
) {
  return () => {
          store.dispatch(AuthActions.isLoggedIn());
  };
}

  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
      deps: [Store],
      multi: true
  }
  ]
```

Inside Auth Effects

```
  isLoggedIn$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.isLoggedIn),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
          switchMap((user: any) => {
            return [
              AuthActions.logInSuccess({ token: user.token, name: user.data.user.name, email: user.data.user.email, id: user.data.user._id, likedProperties: [...user.data.user.likedPropertiesSell, ...user.data.user.likedPropertiesRent], myProfileInformations: userProfile })]
          }),
          catchError(err => {
            return of(AuthActions.logInFail({ error: `code ${err.status}` }))
          }
          )
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

Console log from Auth Guard

```
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070535+00:00 app[web.1]:   isAuthenticated: false,
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070535+00:00 app[web.1]:   user: null,
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070536+00:00 app[web.1]:   errorMessage: 'code undefined',
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070537+00:00 app[web.1]:   likedProperties: null,
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070537+00:00 app[web.1]:   following: null,
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070538+00:00 app[web.1]:   followingListLoaded: false,
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070538+00:00 app[web.1]:   myProfileInformations: null,
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070539+00:00 app[web.1]:   isInitializing: false
2020-12-24T14:01:53.070539+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

So store is setting isInitializing to false before user data is retreived and I really don't know why errorMessage exists there, in redux store logInFail() is never dispatched